# Add prefix to elements of a variadic macro

Tags: c++, c, macros, variadic-functions

I am working on [morphing C++ into Javascript](http://blog.vjeux.com/2011/javascript/jspp-morph-cpp-into-javascript.html) and I would like to write a macro `function` that does the following:

```
function (x, y, z, ...)
to
[=] (var a, var b, var x, var y, var z, ...) -> Object
```

Basically that would be:

```
function() -> "[=] (var a, var b) -> Object"
function(x) -> "[=] (var a, var b, var x) -> Object"
function(x, y) -> "[=] (var a, var b, var x, var y) -> Object"
...
```

It does not have to be variadic, if that can work for a fixed number of elements that works for me. Also if an compiler extension is required, I'm good with it.

For information my current macro is the following

```
#define function(...) [=] (var a, var b, ##__VA_ARGS__) -> Object
```

I tried to look for macro tricks but I can't find something that matches what I need.

Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

You could have a look into [P99](http://p99.gforge.inria.fr/p99-html/group__preprocessor__for.html). It uses variadic macros as of C99 for all sorts of code unrolling.

Answer (score 0):

It is scary what you can do with the [Boost preprocessor](http://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_46_1/libs/preprocessor/doc/) library.  It can probably even handle that@!